# http live streaming for mp3 files

Tags: iphone, ios, linux, http-live-streaming

I need help in converting mp3 files to Apples Http Live Streaming protocol files. I am working on a music application and wants to use Live streaming in this app.

I got this link http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/452/iphone-http-streaming-with-ffmpeg-and-an-open-source-segmenter/ from google but it contains how to live stream video files.

Can anybody help me with mp3 files.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ffmpeg you're also able to convert mp3-files only (no video).
Just use:

```
ffmpeg -i yourmp3.mp3 ...your arguments... output.mp3
```

Comment: ffmpeg -i <in file> -acodec libmp3lame -ar 48000 -ab 64k <output file>

But, why is your mp3 not already supporting Apple's protocol? I've never seen a mp3 on my iPhone (in Safari) that doesn't fit the protocol...?

Comment: My mp3 is working fine on iPhone but the problem is the app have to be HIG compatible. iPhone and iPad apps that send large amounts of audio or video data over cellular networks are required to use HTTP Live Streaming.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH1-DontLinkElementID_29

Comment: Why don't you use the mediastreamsegmenter-command Apple explains and provides there? (by adding the -audio-only param)

Comment: I can't because the app is for a website(songs get added dynamically, I have to convert each song after upload) and that site is hosted on linux server...

Answer (score 0):

To add to Tim's answer, HLS supports mp3 codec. So if your audio is already in mp3, all you would need is the segmenter

Comment: Segmenter? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Prior to ffmpeg's native capability to output m3u8 files, you would need a third party segmenter to do so. An example [here](https://github.com/johnf/m3u8-segmenter/blob/master/README.md)